# Remove complete element from Array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Im reading documents from firebase and putting them into an Array. The output of my array is:

> [MainApp.Message(name: Optional("Bluesona"), userId:
>   Optional("7epbTeafCAS51ctDxWWt0xIAWN03"), msg: Optional(""), creatAt:
>   Optional(1535028200082), latitude: Optional("0.00"), longitude:
>   Optional("0.00")), MainApp.Message(name: Optional("Oliver"), userId:
>   Optional("7epbTeafCAS51ctDxWWt0xIAWN03"), msg: Optional(""), creatAt:
>   Optional(1537440120260), latitude: Optional("54.976663"), longitude:
>   Optional("-7.732037")), MainApp.Message(name: Optional("Oliver"),
>   userId: Optional("7epbTeafCAS51ctDxWWt0xIAWN03"), msg: Optional(""),
>   creatAt: Optional(1537639139566), latitude: Optional("54.976726"),
>   longitude: Optional("-7.731986"))]

How can I then manipulate my array to only display items which have name "Bluesona"?

Here is the code where I'm creating my array

```
    firebaseDB.collection("message").document(key).collection("messages").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        }
        else {
            self.dataArr.removeAll()
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                let msgdata = document.data() as! [String:Any]
                var msgObj = Message()
                if let name = msgdata["name"] as? String {

                    msgObj.name = name
                }

                if let latitude = msgdata["latitude"] as? String {

                    msgObj.latitude = latitude
                }
                if let long = msgdata["longitude"] as? String {

                    msgObj.longitude = long
                }

                if let uid = msgdata["userId"] as? String {

                    msgObj.userId = uid
                }
                if let time = msgdata["createdAt"] as? Int {

                    msgObj.creatAt = time
                }
                self.dataArr.append(msgObj)
                //                    self.dataArr.append(document.data() as [String:Any])

            }
            self.dataArr = self.dataArr.sorted(by: {$0.creatAt < $1.creatAt })
            self.tblMessage.reloadData()
            if self.dataArr.count < 1 {
                print("No Messages")
            }
            else{
            //self.tblMessage.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.dataArr.count - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
            print(self.dataArr)
            }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give the code where you enter the objects into the array (and set up the array itself?)

Comment: Please add some code, so that we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: Updated question to show Array code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` to achieve your goals.

```
...
self.dataArr = self.dataArr.sorted(by: {$0.creatAt < $1.creatAt })
self.dataArr = dataArr.filter { $0.name == "Bluesona"}
self.tblMessage.reloadData()
...
```

Or you can also use `removeAll(where:)` introduced in Swift4.2:

```
...
self.dataArr = self.dataArr.sorted(by: {$0.creatAt < $1.creatAt })
self.dataArr.removeAll(where: { $0.name != "Bluesona"})
self.tblMessage.reloadData()
...
```

Comment: Or `removeAll(where:)`  as a mutating method (new in Swift 4.2?)

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the info, didn't even know about this new method, updated my answer